# How does Self(...) works in swift?

Tags: swift

I saw this piece of code but am not understanding what the syntax does.  I've looked on web, but wasn't able to find anything.

Q1.  What does it do?
Q2.  How would you actually go about finding how a particular syntax works?

```
  public extension AppleMusicClient {
   static let denied = Self(
    musicAuthorizationStatus: .denied,
    playSong: { _ in .none },
    requestMusicAuthorization: { .none },
    searchRequest: { _ in .none }
  )

  static let noop = Self(
    musicAuthorizationStatus: .authorized,
    playSong: { _ in .none },
    requestMusicAuthorization: { .none },
    searchRequest: { _ in .none }
  )
```

Comment: It's in the [book](https://books.apple.com/ca/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-7/id881256329).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms `Self` is just a synonym of the *current* type name, in this case - `AppleMusicClient`. I.e. same static constants could be defined as

```
public extension AppleMusicClient {
   static let denied = AppleMusicClient(...
   static let noop = AppleMusicClient(
```

So why use `Self`, and not type name directly? Best it's described in [the original SR](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0068-universal-self.md):

> - Self is shorter and clearer in its intent. It mirrors self, which refers to the current instance.
> - It provides an easier way to access static members. As type names grow large, readability suffers. MyExtremelyLargeTypeName.staticMember is unwieldy to type and read.
> - Code using hardwired type names is less portable than code that automatically knows its type.
> - Renaming a type means updating any TypeName references in code.

See also: [a more detailed explanation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID610).

Regarding Q2 ("*How would you actually go about finding how a particular syntax works?*"): [Swift language reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book) is there for you. Usually, every time you are upgrading your Xcode (which also updates Swift version), it's a good idea to check [Revision History](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/RevisionHistory/RevisionHistory.html) to see what changed for your current Swift version. So for instance the `Self` change is mentioned in Swift 5.1 changelog:

> Updated the Self Type section, now that Self can be used to refer to the type introduced by the current class, structure, or enumeration declaration.